# JQuery Add Dynamic rows along with delete button

Tags: jquery

I have 4 textbox fields I want to give a link to ADD. when clicked on Add it should display the 4 rows belowthe existing rows as well a delete button.

Should be repeated when clicking on ADD.

So delete button should start displaying from second row when clicked on add.

If I click on delete button corresponding row should be deleted

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your current mark-up, your current attempts at a solution, explain what went wrong and *where you're stuck*. As it is this reads like a 'please do my work for me.'

Comment: I'm now voting to close this question, given that, in the six hours since I asked you to supply further details, you appear to have revisited the question, but supplied neither information nor explanation.

Comment: Sorry I actually got some code from this link http://jsbin.com/aciba/13/edit#javascript,html,live . but I was actually lokking how to save it to database using yii framework. So I created one more question with tag yii. Dont know how to close this ticket. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Is this something like that that you want : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/uYTcW/

Comment: but I have a problem here. Actually I am trying to add dropdown lists(instead of empty textboxes) whose values are populated from the database. And also I want to add all these rows tothe database using php. I think it would be better if it is an array